# jQuery: looking through a DIV, getting name that contains WITH id that contains

Tags: jquery

I've got a very interesting need for jQuery.

I need to look into a specific DIV ID and then within that DIV, find an input thats name contains a certain string but is also checked.

```
var exclusionsFridayChecked = $("#divExclusions").find("input[id~='Fridays'][type='checked']").length;

// hoping to get '1' if it is checked
```

But that doesn't work... my syntax is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `~=` selector "selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces".

Since ids cannot contain spaces, I'm guessing that you want `*=`, which "selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring".

So, you can try using

```
$("#divExclusions input[id*='Fridays']:checked")
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense because the string is technically connected by periods. Thank you, Emmett!

Comment: Although you did change `id` to `name` ^^

Comment: is there a way to turn this statement into a bool?

Comment: @dcolumbus What you have is fine. `var bool = $("foo").length;`

Answer (score 0):

///.length should be a function so .length() EDIT: NOT WORKING

Maybe jQuery returns as an array so you could try using
$("#divExclusions").find("input[id~='Fridays'][type='checked']")[0].length

Comment: In Javascript, `length` is a property, not a function.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `length()` function.

Comment: Sorry I was confused by height() and width()